# cron job doesn't run under specific account

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have a crontab entry on my RHEL 5.4 system under the "oracle" account but it never seems to actually run.  I have the following entry:

```
* * * * * /home/oracle/blahblah.sh > /tmp/test.log 2>&1
```

Since "blahblah.sh" does not actually exist I would expect to see an error in /tmp/test/log.  If I make a similar crontab entry in my personal account, the entry does run and I get the following output in test.log:

```
/bin/sh: /home/username/blahblah.sh: No such file or directory
```

It seems like cron jobs are simply not running under only one specific account (oracle).  Why would this be happening?  Note that we are using Active Directory but I don't believe that has anything to do with this problem since both accounts I am testing with authenticate through AD.

Comment: Do you have `/etc/cron.allow` or `/etc/cron.deny` files, and are there any mention of the `oracle` user in those?  Anything in the `cron` logs?

Comment: Is `/tmp/test.log` writeable by the `oracle` user?

Comment: No /etc/cron.allow or cron.deny.  Yes, /tmp/tst.log is writeable.

Comment: Can you post the output of `crontab -l | od -xc` as user `oracle`?  If commands in your cron don't end in a newline `\n` then cron won't run them, perhaps there is something up with your crontab editor config, custom `vi` settings etc.

Comment: The output of:  "crontab -l | grep od -xc" is:

0